# Upload image file importing pypyodbc from python

Tags: python, sql-server

*From python importing pypyodbc as I'm trying to insert image file to SQL Server*

```
SQLInsertImg = "insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset (Bulk 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Capture.JPG', Single_Blob) as img"
```

**In python shell**

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 72-73: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

The same query, when executed in MSSQL query sheet, results holds good what might be the error occurred?

I have answered to my question now problems arises with

```
import pypyodbc

cnxn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
                    'Server=DESKTOP-C6RS3DO;'
                    'Database=demo2016;'
                    'uid=sa;pwd=sa')
print('connected <br/>')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

SQLInsertImg = "insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset (Bulk 'C:\\Users\PC\Desktop\Capture.JPG', Single_Blob) as img"
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1626, in execute
        self.execdirect(query_string)
      File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1652, in execdirect
        check_success(self, ret)
      File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1007, in check_success
        ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
      File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 975, in ctrl_err
        raise ProgrammingError(state,err_text)
    pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\Capture.JPG" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).')
```

**After executing     `cursor = cnxn.cursor()` in python shell results above?**

Answer (score 0):

Typical error on Windows because the default user directory is `C:\user\<your_user>`, so when you want to use this path as an string parameter into a Python function, you get a Unicode error, just because the `\u` is a Unicode escape. Any character not numeric after this produces an error.

To solve it, just double the backslashes: `C:\\\user\\\<\your_user>...`